# Windows updates failure configuring updates

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update

I recently got a new computer and when I try to install the updates I get the following error `Failure configuring windows updates, reverting changes`

This issue is really annoying because I can install all of the other updates fine, but it's just 2 that wont budge, the updates that wont work are internet explorer 11 and a security update that I will comment the code later.

OS is a windows 7 ultimate 64bit. Thank you in advance

Comment: Your not on service pack 1 right?

Comment: Well i think i am.

Comment: copy the folder C:\windows\logs\CBS to the desktop, zip this folder, upload the zip to cloud service and post a link to the zip here.

Comment: Ok i give you a media fire link in the next 3 or so hours. just at school atm :P

Comment: Here is the link: https://www.mediafire.com/?gajf23jm6bhyqsn

Comment: Are you currently on explorer 10? Two things I would check is go to windows update and open "restore hidden updates". Make sure there are no updates that are hidden that explorer may need. If not I would maybe try going to "installed updates" and unistall explorer 10, reboot and reinstall. I know I've had this issue before, I just apologize I can't remember how I fixed it. Honestly though I made the switch to chrome and am much happier with that.

Comment: no im on internet explorer 8 i think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several issues.

some metadata are missing/corrupted:

```
2014-07-29 15:49:15, Info                  CSI    00000229 Couldn't find the hash of component: Microsoft-Windows-ieframe, Version = 11.2.9600.17207, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_IA32_ON_WIN64 (10), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the catalog [l:192{96}]"\SystemRoot\WinSxS\Catalogs\f967e3adade5a1edc1e6d622347f3de0c670e610d5a708a65aa0059ef98a0455.cat".

2014-07-29 15:49:15, Error                 CSI    0000022a@2014/7/29:05:49:15.671 (F) d:\win7sp1_gdr\base\wcp\componentstore\csd_winners.cpp(1302): Error 80092004 [Warning,Facility=FACILITY_NTSSPI,Code=8196 (0x2004)] originated in function CCSDirectTransaction::AddImplicationsToCatalogsAndVerifyComponentHashes expression: (null)
[gle=0x80004005]
2014-07-29 15:49:19, Error                 CSI    0000022b (F) 80092004 [Warning,Facility=FACILITY_NTSSPI,Code=8196 (0x2004)] #1820275# from CCSDirectTransaction::PrepareForCommit(...)[gle=0x90092004]
2014-07-29 15:49:19, Error                 CSI    0000022c (F) 80092004 [Warning,Facility=FACILITY_NTSSPI,Code=8196 (0x2004)] #1820274# from CCSDirectTransaction::ExamineTransaction(...)[gle=0x90092004]
2014-07-29 15:49:19, Error                 CSI    0000022d (F) 80092004 [Warning,Facility=FACILITY_NTSSPI,Code=8196 (0x2004)] #1820273# from CCSDirectTransaction_IRtlTransaction::ExamineTransaction(...)[gle=0x90092004]
2014-07-29 15:49:19, Error                 CSI    0000022e (F) CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND #1820023# from Windows::COM::CPendingTransaction::IStorePendingTransaction_Analyze(...)[gle=0x80092004]
2014-07-29 15:49:20, Error                 CSI    0000022f (F) CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND #1816617# from Windows::ServicingAPI::CCSITransaction::ICSITransaction_Commit(Flags = 47 (0x0000002f), pSink = NULL, disp = 0, coldpatching = FALSE)[gle=0x80092004]
2014-07-29 15:49:20, Error                 CSI    00000230 (F) CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND #1816616# 5501824 us from Windows::ServicingAPI::CCSITransaction_ICSITransaction::Commit(flags = 0x0000002f, pSink = NULL, disp = 0)
[gle=0x80092004]
2014-07-29 15:49:20, Error                 CBS    Exec: Failed to commit CSI transaction to resolve execution chain. [HRESULT = 0x80092004 - CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND]
```

an `STATUS_TRANSACTION_NOT_ACTIVE` error:

```
2014-07-29 16:51:44, Error                 CSI    00000006 (F) Error: ResolvePendingTransactions called after poqexec failure (call 1)
  Status = STATUS_TRANSACTION_NOT_ACTIVE, Operation = HardLinkFile, DiagString = [l:432{216}]"\SystemRoot\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-network-security_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.18283_none_2afda92041642eb6\NetworkSecurity-ppdlic.xrm-ms, \??\C:\Windows\System32\spp\tokens\ppdlic\NetworkSecurity-ppdlic.xrm-ms"
[gle=0x80004005]
```

You should run the [checksur tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821/en-us) to [try to fix those issues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619779%28WS.10%29.aspx). After you did this try again to install the updates.

If nothing helps, repair your Windows with an [Inplace upgrade.](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html)